# Return all with birthdate occurring after death date

Tags: r, date

I have a dataset of people. For each individual they have a name, their date of birth (DOB), and their date of death (DOD). Some of the DODs occur before the DOB, which is obviously an error. How can I tell R to return all individuals with a DOB occurring after the DOD?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you provide a minimally reproducible example? It doesn't have to be exact data but close to where we can work with it.

Comment: Assuming a dataframe named `df` with date of birth column `dob` and date of death column `dod`, where both `df$dob` and `df$dod` are of class `Date`, have you tried something like `df[df$dob > df$dod, ]`? If so, what error did you experience, or how did your output differ from your expected output? If not, does that accomplish what you need?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have your data stored in `df`. In order to display the rows where DOB happens after DOD:

```
df[df$DOB > df$DOD, ]
```

In order to filter out the errors, do the following:

```
df[df$DOB <= df$DOD, ]
```

Comment: Incorrect number of dimensions; i.e. change `df[df$DOB > df$DOD]` to `df[df$DOB > df$DOD, ]`, etc.

Comment: Yes! I've been working on `data.table` and I forget `data.frame` needs the `,`. I have updated the answer.